# Slick on Click change to specific slide

Tags: javascript, carousel, slick.js

I want to change slick slide position by tabs.
I have tabs and I need to go to specific slide by clicking on tab.
Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added your markup and the JavaScript you're using to initialize/control your slideshow. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your beforeChange event as below

```
$('.slideshow').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){l
$(".slick-slide").removeClass('works');
$('.slick-current').addClass('works');        
});
```